# objective C examples of the new clustering API in MKMAPView introduced in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I am trying to implement the new MKMAPView clustering API (introduced in iOS 11) in my project and need help understanding how to use it in Objective C. I see a lot of examples in Swift but I am not very familiar with Swift so it is difficult to convert them into Objective C.

Help will be appreciated.

Edit -

This is what is currently done -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    ...
    [self method1:listArray];
}

- (void) method1: (NSArray*) list {
    //adding annotations to mapview by fetching list from array
    ...
    ...
    ...
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:   (id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    CustomAnnotation * customView = (CustomAnnotation*)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"annotation"];
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return customView;
}
```

Comment: please include which part of the code you're not familiar

Comment: @aldok: I have edited my question to include the code fragment. I am not sure how to proceed further.